# Неестественное отталкивание шаров

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, графика, геометрия, физика

Делаю программу, где шарики (Shape) отталкиваются от стен и друг от друга. С отталкивание от стен проблем нет, но вот отталкивание друг от друга выглядит неестественно. Шары телепортируются, иногда отталкиваются от воздуха.

Это часть кода, отвечающая за полет шаров и отталкивание от стен:

```
for i := 0 to 7 do
begin
  masPosX[i] := masPosX[i] + masVelX[i];
  masPosY[i] := masPosY[i] + masVelY[i];
if masPosX[i] > ClientWidth - Shp1.Width then
begin
  masPosX[i] := ClientWidth - Shp1.Width;
  masVelX[i] := -masVelX[i];
end
else if masPosX[i] < 0 then
begin
  masPosX[i] := 0;
  masVelX[i] := -masVelX[i];
end;
if masPosY[i] > ClientHeight - Shp1.Width then
begin
  masPosY[i] := ClientHeight - Shp1.Width;
  masVelY[i] := -masVelY[i];
end
else if masPosY[i] < 0 then
begin
  masPosY[i] := 0;
  masVelY[i] := -masVelY[i];
end;
end;
```

А это часть кода, которая отвечает за отталкивание друг от друга:

```
for i := 0 to 7 do
for j := 0 to 7 do
  if i <> j then
  begin
        a := MasPosX[i] - MasPosX[j];
        b := MasPosY[i] - MasPosY[j];
        dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));

        if dist <= 65 then
        begin
          bet := arctan2(MasPosY[j] - MasPosY[i], MasPosX[j] - MasPosX[i]);
          x1 := masvelx[i] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[i] * sin(-bet);
          y1 := MasVelX[i] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[i] * cos(-bet);
          x2 := MasVelX[j] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[j] * sin(-bet);
          y2 := MasVelX[j] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[j] * cos(-bet);
          MasVelX[i] := x2 * cos(bet) - y1 * sin(bet);
          MasVelY[i] := x2 * sin(bet) + y1 * cos(bet);
          masVelX[j] := x1 * cos(bet) - y2 * sin(bet);
          MasVelY[j] := x1 * sin(bet) + y2 * cos(bet);

          kk := 1;
          while (dist <= 65) and (kk < 100) do
          begin
            inc(kk);
            a := MasPosX[i] - MasPosX[j];
            b := MasPosY[i] - MasPosY[j];
            dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));

            MasPosX[i] := MasPosX[i] + MasVelX[i] * 0.1;
            MasPosY[i] := MasPosY[i] + MasVelY[i] * 0.1;

            MasPosX[j] := MasPosX[j] + MasVelY[j] * 0.1;
            MasPosY[j] := MasPosY[j] + MasVelY[j] * 0.1;
          end;                            
        end;
    end;
```

Ошибка скорее всего находится этой части кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for h0 := 0 to ballcount - 1 do
begin
  for h1 := 0 to ballcount - 1 do
    if h0 <> h1 then
    begin
      a := MasPosX[h0] + MasVelX[h0] * 0.001 - MasPosX[h1] - MasVelX[h1] * 0.001;
      b := MasPosY[h0] + MasVelY[h0] * 0.001 - MasPosY[h1] - MasVelY[h1] * 0.001;
      dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));
      if dist <= 241 then// если удар то
      begin
        bet := arctan2(MasPosY[h1] - MasPosY[h0], MasPosX[h1] - MasPosX[h0]); //меняем направление
        x1 := masvelx[h0] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[h0] * sin(-bet);
        y1 := MasVelX[h0] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[h0] * cos(-bet);
        x2 := MasVelX[h1] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[h1] * sin(-bet);
        y2 := MasVelX[h1] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[h1] * cos(-bet);
        MasVelX[h0] := x2 * cos(bet) - y1 * sin(bet);
        MasVelY[h0] := x2 * sin(bet) + y1 * cos(bet);
        masVelX[h1] := x1 * cos(bet) - y2 * sin(bet);
        MasVelY[h1] := x1 * sin(bet) + y2 * cos(bet);
        n := 0;
        xx0 := masvelx[h0];
        yy0 := masvely[h0];
        xx1 := masvelx[h1];
        yy1 := masvely[h1];
        repeat  //пытаемся раздвинуть шары,
          MasPosX[h0] := MasPosX[h0] + xx0 * 0.0011;
          MasPosY[h0] := MasPosY[h0] + yy0 * 0.0011;
          MasPosX[h1] := MasPosX[h1] + xx1 * 0.0011;
          MasPosY[h1] := MasPosY[h1] + yy1 * 0.0011;
          a := MasPosX[h0] - MasPosX[h1];
          b := MasPosY[h0] - MasPosY[h1];
          dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));
          inc(n);
        until (dist > 241) or (n > 50000);

      end;
    end;

  MasPosX[h0] := MasPosX[h0] + MasVelX[h0] * 0.001;
  MasPosY[h0] := MasPosY[h0] + MasVelY[h0] * 0.001;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Проблема вашего кода - в том, что вы пытаетесь сначала вычислить новую скорость - а потом дополнительно продвинуть шары, разведя их на расстояние после удара. Именно второй шаг дает неестественность: после каждого удара шары как бы "прыгает" вперед по времени.

Ваш внутренний цикл - попросту лишний. Не надо специально разводить шары, надо просто продолжить симуляцию и они сами разлетятся куда надо.

Насколько я понимаю, внутренним циклом вы пытались решить проблему, когда шары отказывались разлетаться за 1 тик симуляции и на следующий тик столкновение детектировалось опять, что опять-таки приводило к нереалистичному столкновению.

Избежать этого можно двумя путями.

Во-первых, можно использовать динамический шаг по времени, уменьшая его до тех пор пока шары не перестанут перекрываться и не начнут касаться друг друга. Подобрать такой шаг можно итерационно или геометрически.

Во-вторых, можно просто уменьшать квант времени пока симуляция не станет походить на реалистичную.

Answer (score 0):

A[1,x] - х координата
A[2,x] - у координата
A[3,x] - dх скорость передвижения по х
A[4,x] - dу скорость передвижения по у

```
for j:=1 to n do
 begin
  if  (a[1,j]<0) or (a[1,j]>panel1.Width) then
   a[3,j]:=-a[3,j];

  if  (a[2,j]<0) or (a[2,j]>panel1.Height ) then
   a[4,j]:=-a[4,j];

  for i:=j to n do
   if i<>j then
   begin
   dist:=sqrt(sqr(a[1,j]-a[1,i])+sqr(a[2,j]-a[2,i]));
   if dist<d then
   begin

    aa:=a[1,j]-a[1,i];
    bb:=a[2,j]-a[2,i];

    p1:=aa*bb/sqr(dist);
    p2:=sqr(aa/dist);
    p3:=sqr(bb/dist);

    d1:=a[4,j]*p1+a[3,j]*p2-a[4,i]*p1-a[3,i]*p2;
    d2:=a[3,j]*p1+a[4,j]*p3-a[3,i]*p1-a[4,i]*p3;

    a[3,j]:=a[3,j]-d1;
    a[4,j]:=a[4,j]-d2;
    a[3,i]:=a[3,i]+d1;
    a[4,i]:=a[4,i]+d2;


     p3:=(d-dist)/2; //при соударении шары всегда "проникают" друг в друга, поэтому раздвигаем их
     p1:=p3*(aa/dist);
     p2:=p3*(bb/dist);
     a[1,j]:=a[1,j]+p1;
     a[2,j]:=a[2,j]+p2;
     a[1,i]:=a[1,i]-p1;
     a[2,i]:=a[2,i]-p2;

     a[5,i]:= random;
     a[6,i]:= random;
     a[7,i]:= random;

     a[5,j]:= random;
     a[6,j]:= random;
     a[7,j]:= random;
    end
  end;
  a[1,j]:=a[1,j]+a[3,j];
  a[2,j]:=a[2,j]+a[4,j];

 end;
```

Comment: А это зачем? `a[5,i]:= random;      a[6,i]:= random;      a[7,i]:= random;`

Comment: И сделайте лучше не двумерный массив, а массив рекордов (`array of record x,y,dx,dy: Single; end;`), так будет не в пример понятнее.

Comment: a[5,i]:= random; a[6,i]:= random; a[7,i]:= random;
Там у меня цвета в RGB были. Условие программы было что бы все в одном массиве, так что не пинайте.

Comment: Вы автор вопроса? Объедините аккаунты :-)

Comment: И еще совет, для ускорения, не вычисляйте sqrt, там где можете сравнивать квадраты ;-)

Comment: Я не автор, был готовый код - поделился.